# summing up the total of an invoice per customer

Tags: xslt, xslt-1.0

i need a way to come up with the total of the invoices per customer,.(add the three invoices then display the total accordingly),.have tried sum(/*/(PriceUnit*Ordered)),.but its not working error,.---[the total of an invoice=PriceUnit*Ordered],.so sum up the three invoice and then display the results,.its tough for me so please help

## Sample input document

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="Nom.xslt"?>
<customers>
  <customer>
    <clientname>troy madison</clientname>
    <invoices>
    <invoiceDate>8/8/98</invoiceDate>
      <product>
         <PriceUnit>1000</PriceUnit>
         <Ordered>2</Ordered>
     </product>
     <product>
         <PriceUnit>5400</PriceUnit>
         <Ordered>3</Ordered>
     </product>
   </invoices>
   <invoices>
     <invoiceDate>1/4/98</invoiceDate>
       <product>
          <PriceUnit>300</PriceUnit>
          <Ordered>4</Ordered>
       </product>
      <product>
        <PriceUnit>6000</PriceUnit>
        <Ordered>1</Ordered>
     </product>
   </invoices>
  <invoices>
    <invoiceDate>03/5/99</invoiceDate>
      <product>
        <PriceUnit>549</PriceUnit>
        <Ordered>1</Ordered>
     </product>
     <product>
       <PriceUnit>320</PriceUnit>
       <Ordered>2</Ordered>
    </product>
   </invoices>
 </customer>
 <customer>
   <clientname>Morris</clientname>
    <invoices>
      <invoiceDate>1/1/00</invoiceDate>
        <product>
           <PriceUnit>59</PriceUnit>
           <Ordered>3</Ordered>
        </product>
      <product>
          <PriceUnit>55</PriceUnit>
          <Ordered>1</Ordered>
      </product>
    </invoices>
    <invoices>
     <invoiceDate>11/1/01</invoiceDate>
       <product>
         <PriceUnit>10</PriceUnit>
         <Ordered>2</Ordered>
      </product>
      <product>
         <PriceUnit>54</PriceUnit>
         <Ordered>1</Ordered>
       </product>
    </invoices>
    <invoices>
      <invoiceDate>03/2/01</invoiceDate>
        <product>
          <PriceUnit>30</PriceUnit>
          <Ordered>1</Ordered>
        </product>
       <product>
         <PriceUnit>299</PriceUnit>
         <Ordered>1</Ordered>
       </product>
    </invoices>
</customer>
</customers>
```

## Expected output

[OP to list expected output here.]

## Style-sheet that I have tried so far

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">
<xsl:template match="customers">
    <html>
        <head>
            <h1>CUSTOMER REFERENCE</h1>
        </head>
        <body bgcolor="#DAF52C">
            <table border="1">
                <tr>
                    <th width="50">NAME</th>
                    <th width="50">INVOICE DATE</th>
                    <th width="50">PRODUCT UNIT</th>
                    <th width="50">ORDERED </th>
                    <th width="50">PRODUCT UNIT</th>
                    <th width="50">ORDERED </th>
                    <th width="50">INVOICE DATE</th>
                    <th width="50">PRODUCT UNIT</th>
                    <th width="50">ORDERED </th>
                    <th width="50">PRODUCT UNIT</th>
                    <th width="50">ORDERED </th>
                    <th width="50">INVOICE DATE</th>
                    <th width="50">PRODUCT UNIT</th>
                    <th width="50">ORDERED </th>
                    <th width="50">PRODUCT UNIT</th>
                    <th width="50">ORDERED </th>
                    <th width="50">INVOICE TOTAL</th>
                </tr>
                <xsl:for-each select="customer">
                    <tr>
                        <td><xsl:value-of select="clientname"/></td>
                        <xsl:for-each select="invoices">
                            <td><xsl:value-of select="invoiceDate"/></td>
                            <xsl:for-each select="product">
                                <td><xsl:value-of select="PriceUnit"/></td>
                                <td><xsl:value-of select="Ordered"/></td>
                            </xsl:for-each>
                        </xsl:for-each>
                    </tr>
                </xsl:for-each>
            </table>
        </body>
    </html>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Which XSLT processor do you use, is that an XSLT 2.0 processor like Saxon or AltovaXML or XmlPrime? Only with XSLT 2.0 you can use expressions like `sum(.//product/(PriceUnit * Ordered))`.

Comment: @martin honnen its 1.0,.thanks for that

Comment: i want a way to get the invoice total per customer eg morris-

Comment: This is an exact reproduction of your previous question. Your previous question was closed because you inexplicably refused to state your expected result. Could I suggest that you provide your expected output from this sample input?

Comment: Your style-sheet was hidden from SO users because of some poor formatting choices in your question. I have edited you question to make it visible. This should make a difference.

Comment: Is it always precisely 3 invoices per customer? Or can it vary? And how many products per invoice? Is that fixed too (at 2 products per invoice)? or can it vary too?

Comment: @ Sean B Durkin-what i want is the last column should have the invoice total of which is an sum of the total invoice totals[the three invoices added together then dispaly the amount on the coulmn,.my previous XSLT sheet was working displaying everything apart form the sum of invoices totals.The one you provided isnt working,.thats why i reposted the question for clarity purpose,.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Here is a pure XSLT 1.0 solution that doesn't require any extension functions:**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>
 <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

 <xsl:template match="/*">
  <html>
    <table border="1">
     <thead>
       <tr>
         <td>Name</td><td>Total</td>
       </tr>
     </thead>
     <xsl:apply-templates/>
    </table>
  </html>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match="customer">
  <tr>
    <td><xsl:value-of select="clientname"/></td>
    <td>
      <xsl:call-template name="sumProducts">
       <xsl:with-param name="pNodes" select="invoices/product"/>
       <xsl:with-param name="pName1" select="'PriceUnit'"/>
       <xsl:with-param name="pName2" select="'Ordered'"/>
      </xsl:call-template>
    </td>
  </tr>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template name="sumProducts">
   <xsl:param name="pNodes"/>
   <xsl:param name="pName1"/>
   <xsl:param name="pName2"/>
   <xsl:param name="pAccum" select="0"/>

   <xsl:choose>
     <xsl:when test="not($pNodes)">
       <xsl:value-of select="$pAccum"/>
     </xsl:when>
     <xsl:otherwise>
      <xsl:call-template name="sumProducts">
        <xsl:with-param name="pNodes" select="$pNodes[position() >1]"/>
        <xsl:with-param name="pName1" select="$pName1"/>
        <xsl:with-param name="pName2" select="$pName2"/>
        <xsl:with-param name="pAccum" select=
        "$pAccum + $pNodes[1]/*[name()=$pName1] * $pNodes[1]/*[name()=$pName2]"/>
      </xsl:call-template>
     </xsl:otherwise>
   </xsl:choose>
 </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**When this transformation is applied on the provided XML document:**

```
<customers>
    <customer>
        <clientname>troy madison</clientname>
        <invoices>
            <invoiceDate>8/8/98</invoiceDate>
            <product>
                <PriceUnit>1000</PriceUnit>
                <Ordered>2</Ordered>
            </product>
            <product>
                <PriceUnit>5400</PriceUnit>
                <Ordered>3</Ordered>
            </product>
        </invoices>
        <invoices>
            <invoiceDate>1/4/98</invoiceDate>
            <product>
                <PriceUnit>300</PriceUnit>
                <Ordered>4</Ordered>
            </product>
            <product>
                <PriceUnit>6000</PriceUnit>
                <Ordered>1</Ordered>
            </product>
        </invoices>
        <invoices>
            <invoiceDate>03/5/99</invoiceDate>
            <product>
                <PriceUnit>549</PriceUnit>
                <Ordered>1</Ordered>
            </product>
            <product>
                <PriceUnit>320</PriceUnit>
                <Ordered>2</Ordered>
            </product>
        </invoices>
    </customer>
    <customer>
        <clientname>Morris</clientname>
        <invoices>
            <invoiceDate>1/1/00</invoiceDate>
            <product>
                <PriceUnit>59</PriceUnit>
                <Ordered>3</Ordered>
            </product>
            <product>
                <PriceUnit>55</PriceUnit>
                <Ordered>1</Ordered>
            </product>
        </invoices>
        <invoices>
            <invoiceDate>11/1/01</invoiceDate>
            <product>
                <PriceUnit>10</PriceUnit>
                <Ordered>2</Ordered>
            </product>
            <product>
                <PriceUnit>54</PriceUnit>
                <Ordered>1</Ordered>
            </product>
        </invoices>
        <invoices>
            <invoiceDate>03/2/01</invoiceDate>
            <product>
                <PriceUnit>30</PriceUnit>
                <Ordered>1</Ordered>
            </product>
            <product>
                <PriceUnit>299</PriceUnit>
                <Ordered>1</Ordered>
            </product>
        </invoices>
    </customer>
</customers>
```

**the wanted, correct result is produced**:

```
<html>
   <table border="1">
      <thead>
         <tr>
            <td>Name</td>
            <td>Total</td>
         </tr>
      </thead>
      <tr>
         <td>troy madison</td>
         <td>26589</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
         <td>Morris</td>
         <td>635</td>
      </tr>
   </table>
</html>
```

**Explanation**:

1. A recursively called named template (`sumProducts`), which takes as parameters a node-set (`$pNodes`) of the nodes whose children's products should be summed and the names of the two children elements (`$pName1` and `$pName2`), the products of whose values should be summed. There is a last, auxiliary parameter `$pAccum` with initial value 0, that is used to store the accumulated result between each recursive call.
2. Stop condition is when the passed `pNodes` nodeset is empty. In this case we output the accumulated sum (`$pAccum`).
3. If the stop condition is false, we call ourselves with `$pNodes` in which the first node is removed, and with a new value of `$pAccum`, to which we have added the current product.

**Do note**:

The `sumProducts` template is very generic and can be used in any case where sum of products is required.

**Thus it deserves to be placed in its own stylesheet file, that will be *imported* by other stylesheets** whenever sum of products is needed.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the XSLT 1.0 equivalent of [Dimitre's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12334253/10823) to your first posting of this question.

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
  xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
  xmlns:exsl="http://exslt.org/common"
  xmlns:so="https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12338944"
  exclude-result-prefixes="xsl exsl so">
<xsl:output method="html" />
<xsl:strip-space elements="*" />

 <xsl:template match="/*">
  <html>
    <table border="1">
     <thead>
       <tr>
         <td>Name</td><td>Total</td>
       </tr>
     </thead>
     <xsl:apply-templates/>
    </table>
  </html>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match="customer">
  <tr>
    <td><xsl:value-of select="clientname"/></td>
    <td>
      <xsl:variable name="sales">
        <xsl:for-each select="invoices/product">
          <so:sale><xsl:value-of select="PriceUnit * Ordered"/></so:sale>
        </xsl:for-each>
      </xsl:variable>
      <xsl:value-of select="sum(exsl:node-set($sales)/so:sale)"/>
      </td>
  </tr>
 </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

On the sample document, this yields output...

```
<html>
  <table border="1">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <td>Name</td>
        <td>Total</td>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tr>
      <td>troy madison</td>
      <td>26589</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Morris</td>
      <td>635</td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</html>
```

Comment: <xsl:value-of select="sum(exsl:node-set($sales)/so:sale)"/>,..can someone explain it to me,..not getting anything,.when i run it aint working?

Comment: How are you progressing with that listing of expected output?

Comment: "when i run it aint working" is meaningless. In what way is it not working? How does the actual output (listed above) differ from your expected output (which you forgot to list)? Please provide details.

Comment: Also if transforming via a browser, what browser are you using and what version?

Comment: am using edit plus for the job it brings up an error on the line of code[<xsl:value-of select="sum(exsl:node-set($sales)/so:sale)"/>].the part am not getting is the ::<xsl:value-of select="sum(exsl:node-set($sales)/so:sale)"/>:::what does it do,.